# How to use External login from PhoneGap and Web Api 2?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, asp.net-web-api

I want to put a external login (eg: Facebook) in my phonegap application. For that I write following code:

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl" ng-init="intLoginProvider()">
    <div class="row ">
        <div ng-repeat="provider in loginProvider">
            <a ng-src="{{provider.Url}}">
                <div id='{{provider.Name}}' style="width: 300px; height: 57px;">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All data are come from Web-Api2 and placed hear correctly.

But my problem is I don`t understand how to navigate login provider page and after successfully login it will back my application?